# 403 Forbidden / Google Cloud Translate API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-translate

When we tried to send an API request to the Google Translate API from the m8market.com domain and IP address, we received an error: "403 Forbidden". This exact API key is working successfully on 3 other websites. There are no restrictions on this API key.

Is it possible that we have a country block? Our servers have Russian IP addresses. The API key works fine on 3 other websites that are hosted on non-Russian IP addresses.

Comment: Edit your post. Show the HTTP Request and Response including HTTP headers.